# Load namespaces and class dynamically

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I'm trying to load a namespace and a class with name I only know by the value of a variable.

I'm trying with this:

```
<php
/** 
 * Namespaces and class have the same name.
 */

require_once($arg1 . '.class.php');

use \$arg1\$arg1;

/** 
 * also I have try
 * use \{$arg1}\{$arg1};
 */
 $object = new $arg1();
 var_dump($object);
?>
```

It gives me back:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$arg1' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/vagrant/execute.php on line 5

There are any way to load this, or I try to make it with a factory pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, (not sure about PHP7) chaining variables or constants in namespaces invocation is NOT possible.

in case you only would want load a class depending of a changing value in a variable (coming in $argv or $_GET or whatever) i usually do something like:
(it's a console script)

```
<?php
class foo {
    function foo() {
        print "Hello! i'm foo class \n";
    }
}

class quux {
    function quux() {
        print "Hello! i'm quux class \n";
    }
    function another_method() {
        print "Bye! i'm another method \n";
    }
}


$var = $argv[1];
$obj = new $var;
if ("quux" == $var){
    $obj->another_method();
}
```

this is the output i get :)

```
∙ php oskar.php foo                                       9:58  leandro@montana
Hello! i'm foo class 
~
∙ php oskar.php quux                                      9:59  leandro@montana
Hello! i'm quux class 
Bye! i'm another method
```

in fact, you can do `new $argv[1]` directly but you can't do `new $argv[1]->another_method();` xD

Answer (score 0):

which PHP version you are running & have you tried this :

```
require_once $arg1 . ".class.php";
```

Comment: My php version is PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1, and I have also chante to require_once $arg1 . ".class.php"; But have the same error.